# Concurrent File write between processes

Tags: c++, .net, synchronization, c++-cli, mutex

I need to write log data into a single file from different processes.

I am using Windows Mutex which needs Common Language Runtime support for it.

```
Mutex^ m = gcnew Mutex( false,"MyMutex" );
m->WaitOne();
//... File Open and Write ..
m->ReleaseMutex()
```

Do I really need to change from C++ to C++/CLI for synchronization?

It is ok if the atomic is not used. But I need to know whether using this Mutex will slow down the performance compared to local mutex.

Comment: I'm note quite sure what you are asking: whether there is a different solution without /clr (yes, many), or if such a different solution is measurably faster (probably not), or something else...

Comment: The problem is an #include that you did not show, lousy snippet.  The .h files that have definitions for unmanaged threading primitives like std::thread, std::mutex, etc strictly implement the rule that a managed program may not assume that a managed thread is guaranteed to run on an unmanaged operating system thread.  That never happens in practice but is technically feasible.  You must not #include these kind of files, use pimpl if necessary to keep them out of your own .h files.

Comment: Using the Windows Mutex makes the work simple.. So i thought of opting it. If it is not an good method then what else can i do for doing concurrent writes to a file from different processes?

Comment: how about using Boost::mutex ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding CLR support to your C++ application just to get the Mutex class is overkill. There are several options available to you to synchronize your file access between two applications.

### Option 1: Mutex

If you need to write a file from multiple processes, using a mutex is a good way to do it. Use the [mutex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686927.aspx) [functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686360.aspx#mutex_functions) in the Win32 API. (The .Net Mutex class is just a wrapper around those functions anyway.)

```
HANDLE mutex = CreateMutex(NULL, false, "MyMutex");

DWORD waitResult = WaitForSingleObject(mutex, INFINITE);
if (waitResult == WAIT_OBJECT_0)
{
    // TODO: Write the file
    WriteFile(...);

    ReleaseMutex(mutex);
}
```

As the other answer noted, you will need to open the file with sharing, so that both of your applications can open it at once. However, that by itself may not be enough: If both of your applications are trying to write to the same area of the file, then you'll still need to make sure that only one application writes at a time. Imagine if both applications look at the size of the file, then both try to write to that byte offset at the same time: Even though both tried to just append to the end of the file, they ended up clobbering each other.

### Option 2: Open as append only

If you're purely writing to the end of the file, and not ever attempting to read anything or to write anywhere other than the very end of the file, then there is a special mode you can use that will let you not use a mutex. If you open the file with `dwDesiredAccess` set to `FILE_APPEND_DATA | SYNCHRONIZE` **and nothing else** (don't include `FILE_WRITE_DATA`), then the OS will take care of making sure that all the data that gets written to the file at the end, and the two applications writing data do not overwrite each other. This behavior is documented on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff548289.aspx):

> If only the FILE_APPEND_DATA and SYNCHRONIZE flags are set, the caller can write only to the end of the file, and any offset information about writes to the file is ignored. However, the file will automatically be extended as necessary for this type of write operation.

### Option 3: LockFile

One other path you can take is to use the `LockFile` method. With [`LockFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365202.aspx) (or [`LockFileEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365203.aspx)), you can have both applications open the file, and have each app lock the section of the file that it wants to write to. This gives you more granularity than the mutex, allowing non-overlapping writes to happen at the same time. (Using `LockFile` on the entire file will give you the same basic effect as the mutex, with the added benefit that it will prevent other applications from writing the file while you're doing so.) There's a good example of how to use `LockFile` on [Raymond Chen's blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20151127-00/?p=92211).

Answer (score 1):

Actually you don't need to use a separate mutex at all, you can just use the file itself. When a file is opened with the CreateFile API call (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), the call takes a parameter called dwShareMode which specifiew what concurrent access is allowed by other processes. A value of 0 would prevent other processes from opening the file completely.

Pretty much all APIs to open a file map to CreateFile under the hood, so clr might  be doing the right thing for you when you open a file for writing already.

In the C runtime there is also _fsopen which allows you to open a a file with the sharing flags.

I'd recommend you to test what the default sharing mode is when you open your file from C#. If it does not prevent simultaneous open for writing by default, use _fsopen from C (or maybe there is an appropriate C# function).